# Transform accelerometer data to object space

Tags: math, accelerometer

For the context: I'm developing a embedded system that has an accelerometer built in. This device is connected to a smartphone and streams data (including the accelerometer values). The device can now be attached in any orientation to a vehicle / bike / ...

The Problem: When I receive the accelerometer data from the device, I would like to transform them into the "vehicle-space". What I found out so far is needed:

- A downwards pointing vector, in "device-space" (basically gravitation)
- A forward vector, in "device-space" (pointing in the forward direction of the vehicle)

I have both of this vectors calculated in my application, however I'm now a little bit stuck with the maths / implementation part.

What I found that could possibly a solution is the [Change of Basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis), however I was not able to

- Find a confirmation that this **is** the way to do it
- How to do this in code/pseudo-code

I don't want to include a fat math library for such a "small" task and would rather understand the maths behind it myself.

---

The current solution in my head, which is based on my long-ago memories from university-math and which I have no proof for: (Pseudo-Code)

```
val nfv = normalize(forwardVector)
val ndv = normalize(downwardVector)

val fxd = cross(nfv, ndv)
val rotationMatrix = (
    m11: fxd.x, m12: fxd.y, m13: fxd.z, 
    m21: ndv.x, m22: ndv.y, m23: ndv.z, 
    m31: nfv.x, m32: nfv.y, m33: nfv.z
)

// Then for each "incoming" vector
val transformedVector = rawVector * rotationMatrix
```

---

**Question:** Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Assuming that `nfv` and `ndv` are orthogonal, **yes**. Multiplication with this matrix is equivalent to taking the dot products of the vehicle's basis vectors in "device space", which in turn is equivalent to calculating the components of the acceleration vector in those directions.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Good point. As they **should** be orthogonal, but will never be 100% as they are measured I guess I need something like Gram-Schmidt to ensure that.